# AngularJS disable double click

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with a button which contacts server on click. If you do a double click (or any number of clicks for that matter) you will call the server that number of times.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">{{ 'ADMIN.CONTENT.DELIVERIES.BODY.CLOSE' | translate }}</button>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="vm.markDelivered()" ng-dblclick="return" ng-disabled="flag">{{ 'MANAGER.CONTENT.DELIVERIES.BODY.DELETE_PANEL.CONFIRM' | translate }}</a>
</div>
```

I have tried with `ng-disabled` but for some reason it doesn't work, as it is saying that that element is not allowed there. I tried changing `a` to `button`, but that seems the same. `ng-dblclick="return"` does nothing also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I had the same issue,And solved using this approach.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group pull-right">
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"
    value="Submit" data-ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"
    ng-click="myForm.$invalid=true;vm.markDelivered()" />
</div>
```

So on first click `myForm.$invalid=true` will be set and button will be disabled. SO you will not have multiple calls to your server side code.

Comment: Amazing, slick, simple and effective

Comment: Yeah that even disables your submit button if form validations are not proper.Glad it helped you..!!

Answer (score 1):

So with Bootstrap buttons you won't be able to use ng-disabled. You would have to do it this way:

```
<div class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'disabled': idDisabled}" ng-click="doSomething()">I'm a button!</div>
```

where you are setting the class `disabled` on the button. But this does not disable the action itself. So when the button is pressed you would need to check that `isDisabled` variable and if it is true just return and don't do the intended action.

So for example:

```
doSomething() {
   if (isDisabled) {
       return
   } else {
       // do your server call
       // when call is finished set isDisabled = false
   }
}
```

Comment: Have to use what? :)

Comment: He meant to say use `<button>` instead of `<a>`

Comment: I tried that one also, but it is still telling me that it is not allowed there?

Comment: Oh I know what the issue is I think, I'll edit my answer above

Comment: Just updated my answer. It's because you are using Bootstrap and for some reason bootstrap doesn't work with ng-disabled

Comment: Did that help you?

Comment: dude, you can't use ng-disabled on <a> or <div>. Gotta use a button: <button class="btn btn-default"...

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for us! Thank you so much for the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues here.

First, change the anchor tag to a button.

Second, you seem to be using 'controller as' syntax. So, you are probably setting your `flag` in the `vm`. But, in your html, you are looking for the flag in the `$scope`. Change `ng-disabled="flag"` to `ng-disabled="vm.flag"`

Your final button line would look like this:
`<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="vm.markDelivered()" ng-dblclick="return" ng-disabled="vm.flag">{{ 'MANAGER.CONTENT.DELIVERIES.BODY.DELETE_PANEL.CONFIRM' | translate }}</button>`

Adding a [working plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/uTL4eje96SLOR37xDPoA) demonstrating `ng-disabled`

Comment: it is telling me that `Attribute ng-disabled is not allowed here`? Do you know why is that?

Comment: I've added a working plunker demonstrating `ng-disabled` for a button. Note, it won't work for an `<a>`. You have to change it to a `<button>`

Answer (score 0):

What about using a simple behaviour directive?

```js
function oneTimeCallDirective($timeout) {
  var httpCallMock = (cb = () => 'ok') => $timeout(cb, 5000);

  return function oneTimeCallPostLink(iScope, iElement) {
    let busy = false;
    
    return iElement
      .on('click dblclick', function(event) {
        if(busy) {
          return event.preventDefault();
        }
        
        busy = true;
        
        console.info('Well, Calling.');        
        
        return httpCallMock()
          .then(() => {
            console.log('You Can Start Calling Again');
          })
          .finally(() => {
            busy = false;
          })
        ;
      })
    ;
  };
}

angular
  .module('test', [])
  .directive('oneTimeCall', oneTimeCallDirective)
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
  <button one-time-call>Click Here</button>
</section>
```